# Why does JHipster use field injection and not constructor injection?

Tags: jhipster

JHipster is using field injection in the generated java code. Tools like IntelliJ or SonarQube say this is bad (see squid:S3306). Why doesn't it use constructor injection instead?

Comment: It's valid question. Post it as an issue in jhipster to get some discussion going: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/new

Comment: There are so many reasons why you would do so or the reverse, please do some research about dependency injection in Spring on stackoverflow, you'll find good answers. I don't think it should be posted on github as an issue because it's not an issue and it's very unlikely that we will change our style.

Comment: I see there is some hot debate about this topic and you made a decision. But still I think JHipster should  offer an option to generate with field injection or with constructor injection. That would prevent teams who like to enforce constructor injection from refactoring all the generated code.